# Remove delimiter section from filename with Automator

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, macos

I'm creating an automator script that copies files from one folder to another and then runs an AppleScript to rename the file by splitting via delimiter and resaving with the second item. For example, using file names of:

- a new file$SG789.jpg
- file_2$123-456.jpg
- file_name$LG123.jpg
- this_file$558-432.jpg

I'm trying to split the filename by the "$" dollar sign to create the following new files:

- SG789.jpg
- 123-456.jpg
- LG123.jpg
- 558-432.jpg

However, when I run the script, I get the following error:

*The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error. Can’t get item 2 of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:downloads:Archive:a new file$SG789-PROC.jpg".*

This is the code I'm running in the Run AppleScript workflow:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "$"
    repeat with anItem in input
        set fileName to item 2 of anItem
        return fileName
    end repeat
end run
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing many things wrong:

1. If you set AppleScript's text item delimiters to other then its default `{}`, always reset it to `{}` when finished with the temporary delimiter.
2. `input` is a `list` and as such you should `return` a `list` and do it outside of the `repeat` *loop*.
3. `item 2` within the `repeat` *loop* needs to be `text item 2`, **however**, `anItem` within the `repeat` *loop* in this use case must also be `text`, so it needs to be `(anItem as text)`.
4. `fileName` needs to be a `list` because you are processing a `list` and you need to `return` a `list`.

That said, here's an example Automator workflow with an AppleScript *action* coded in an example manner of how I'd write the *code*. Note though, that while it returns a list of the filenames after the `$` delimiter, I'm not sure what good it's going to do you as it all depends on additional *code* not currently present in this example.

[image: Example Automator Workflow]

AppleScript *code* for the Run AppleScript *action*:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    try
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"$"}
        set theFileNameList to {}
        repeat with thisItem in input
            set the end of theFileNameList to text item 2 of (thisItem as text)
        end repeat
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
        return theFileNameList
    on error eStr number eNum
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with icon caution
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
        return
    end try
end run
```

Comment: Ah! What you pointed out makes sense. This is my first foray into AppleScript and I was cobbling together what I understood from other examples. You mentioned you're not sure what good it's going to do me to get back the list. The next step in the workflow is a Rename Text, since I then need to add the same prefix to all files. Would returning the list be correct or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Yazmin, Since you did not include you entire Automator workflow, what type of workflow it is and all relevant information and the question you asked, "_What am I doing wrong?_" has been answered, I'd suggest you mark my answer appropriately as either helpful (an up-vote) and or the accepted answer (click the check mark), then in a new question continue your quest to do whatever it is you're actually trying to do. You said "_The next step in the workflow is a Rename Text_" and I'm unaware of that Automator _action_.

Comment: @Yazmin, I said "_I'm not sure what good it's going to do you as it all depends on additional code not currently present in this example._" because this answer was meant to point out what was wrong in your code, not fix a broken workflow what has not been presented in it entirety. You certainly can add additional code, as needed/required to do more that what it's presently doing but in all fairness that's outside the scope of the question you asked, "_What am I doing wrong?_" in reference to the AppleScript _code_ in your Run AppleScript _action_ that you presented.

Comment: @Yazmin, You asked "_Would returning the list be correct or is there something I'm missing?_". What's returned is dependent on what's needed and how it's going to be used and without the complete picture I can't say and why you should start a new question with includes the entire Automator workflow, type of workflow, all relevant settings and information, etc.