# Automator to remove all text before hyphen ( - )?

Tags: applescript, bash, automator, script, macos

I'm trying to create an Apple Automator application that will rename a group of files by removing all text before and including a hyphen ( - ) that will post an error if trying to rename a file with *no* hyphen.

ex:

```
input is 001-10312233_033

output is 10312233_033
```

Then if it ran again on the same file (10312233_033) would produce an error or warning as there is no hyphen.

Any ideas what script in Automator will make this happen?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291528/remove-delimiter-section-from-filename-with-automator?rq=1. You could also use a "Shell Script Action" for the renaming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `do shell script` from within AppleScript to invoke a standard UNIX CLI such as `awk`, `sed` or `grep`. In this case since you merely want to find all occurrences of `*-` from the beginning of your string, I'd enlist `sed` to do this.

Something like this will remove everything up to the first dash (`-`):

```
set output to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of input & " | sed 's/.*-//'"
```

#### Example

Say we had this AppleScript:

```
set input to "001-10312233_033"
set output to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of input & " | sed 's/.*-//'"
log "input:  " & input
log "output: " & output
```

This sets your example string as the variable `input`. The 2nd line then takes the variable `input` and echoes the variable to the `sed` command `| sed 's/.*-//'`. This will strip everything (`.*`) up to the first dash, (`-`), encountered, and replaces it with nothing `(//)` in `sed`.

The last 2 commands with the `log` merely echo the 2 variables, `input` & `output`.

Here's the whole thing in action:

```
$ cat regex.sh
#!/bin/bash

osascript <<END
set input to "001-10312233_033"
set output to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of input & " | sed 's/.*-//'"
log "input:  " & input
log "output: " & output
END
```

Make sure the script `regex.sh` is executable:

```
$ chmod + regex.sh
```

And we run it like this:

```
$ ./regex.sh
input:  001-10312233_033
output: 10312233_033
```